# Using underscore js reduce

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, reduce

How does underscorejs `reduce` work?

It's simple to get 
`_.reduce([1, 2, 3], function(memo, num){ return memo + num; }, 0);` (the result is `6`).

But how do the other optional parameters work? In the docs it says:

> Memo is the initial state of the reduction, and each successive step of it should be returned by iterator. The iterator is passed four arguments: the memo, then the value and index (or key) of the iteration, and finally a reference to the entire list."

But I don't understand. I tried to use `reduce` for the following problem, and I couldn't figure it out:

```
var input = [{"score": 2, "name": "Jon", "venue": "A"}, {"score": 3, "name": "Jeff", "venue":"A"}, {"score": 4, "name": "Jon", "venue":"B"}, {"score": 4, "name": "Jeff", "venue":"B"}];

var output = [{"score": 6, "name":"Jon", "venue": ["A", "B"]}, {"score": 7, "name":"Jeff", "venue": ["A", "B"]}];
```

How can I get as output using `_reduce` for input? And it will really helpful how it works inside reduce.

Comment: Please show what you tried so that we can see specifically what you're misunderstanding. The `memo` is simply the initial value at first, then the previous return value for the subsequent iterations. The rest of the arguments are the typical args you'd have for methods like `.map()` or `.forEach()`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Reduce takes a list of values, and reduces it to a single value. What you are trying is not just reduce. You are trying to first group (by name) and then reduce each group. A possible implementation would be something like this, where you first group, and then map each group to a reduce operation that accumulates the score and appends the venue.

```
var input = [
    {"score": 2, "name": "Jon", "venue": "A"}, 
    {"score": 3, "name": "Jeff", "venue":"A"}, 
    {"score": 4, "name": "Jon", "venue":"B"}, 
    {"score": 4, "name": "Jeff", "venue":"B"}];

var output = _.map(_.groupBy(input, "name"), function(group, name) {
    return _.reduce(group, function(memo, elem) { 
            memo.score += elem.score;
            memo.venue.push(elem.venue);
            return memo;
        },
        { name: name, score: 0, venue: [] });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `reduce`, try using plain and simple `each` in this way:

`_.each` admits a third parameter for a context. So, for example:

```
var input = ["Alice", "Bob", "Charlie"];
var context = {};

_.each(input, function(o,i) { this[i] = o; }, context);

console.log(context) //=> {1: "Alice", 2: "Bob", 3: "Charlie"}
```

Ruby has a new method call `each_with_object` similar to reduce for that exact pattern, where the memo is not necessarily the value return (in fact, my function is not returning anything!); but underscore simplifies its API design simply admitting a context for the function as the third parameter.

You can use reduce, but you would need to return the memo each time, making it a bit less elegant IMHO.